# C# linq select some entities

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of answer entities (list size is 50-2000 items - entities have many more properties than shown here)
I want a linq query to select all the entities for those who have not got an answer correct yet
so my output list of entities would exclude all entities by fred and harry from the following table because they each have a correct answer - and include all entities with answers by bob and bill - I have to select on isCorrect and not on the answer itself as the answers are scrambled when presented to the user and I need the full entity as well.

```
- username | answer | isCorrect | .....
- fred     |  a     | false            exclude as he has 1 correct
- fred     |  d     | false            exclude as he has 1 correct
- fred     |  b     | false            exclude as he has 1 correct     
- fred     |  a     | true             exclude as he has 1 correct
+ bob      |  a     | false          need this entity
+ bob      |  b     | false          need this entity
+ bill     |  a     | false          need this entity    
+ bill     |  b     | false          need this entity   
- harry    |  a     | false            exclude as he has 1 correct   
- harry    |  b     | true             exclude as he has 1 correct     
- harry    |  c     | false            exclude as he has 1 correct
```

I can get a list of users with no correct answers

```
var usersWithNoCorrectAnswers = entities
  .GroupBy(a => a.UserName)
  .Where(g => g.Any(x => !x.IsCorrect))
  .Select(g => g.Key)
  .ToList();
```

but I'm not sure how to get a list of entities with no correct answer
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the entities for the users that got all their answers wrong you can group on the username and filter out users that got any correct.  Then just select the entities for the groups and flatten the results.

```
var results = entities.GroupBy(a => a.UserName(
    .Where(g => !g.Any(a => a.IsCorrect))
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I have re- edited to make it clearer I need all the entities and the full entity not just answers, thanks

Comment: @user2153050 OK I've updated my answer to get the entities instead of just the answers, if I understand your changes to the question.

Comment: This worked, I note either of these work      .Where(g => !g.Any(a => a.IsCorrect))   and      .Where(g => g.Any(a => !a.IsCorrect)) .

Comment: @user2153050 Actually it should be `g => !g.Any(a => a.IsCorrect)` or `g => g.All(a => !a.IsCorrect)`  One is not a user with at least one correct and the other is users will all incorrect.

Comment: Yes further experimenting today revealed exactly what you have said here, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
var results = entities.GroupBy(a => a.UserName(
    .Where(g => !g.Any(a => a.IsCorrect))
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(a => 
          new {
               username = a.username,
               answer = a.answer,
               ...
          }
     ))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Or

```
var results = entities.GroupBy(a => a.UserName(
    .Where(g => !g.Any(a => a.IsCorrect))
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(a => a))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

> but I'm not sure how to get a list of entities with no correct answer

```
var noCorrectAnswers = entities
    .GroupBy(q => q.UserName)
    .Where(g => !g.Any(a => a.IsCorrect))
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```